# await Task.Delay(1000); causing crashes - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Main Issue:**
Unsure of what's happening in the background, but apparently whenever the line `await Task.Delay(1000);` is called Unity would turn unresponsive/freezes up.

**Error msg:**
Tried checking callbacks from unity's profiler, but whenever the line in question were triggered unity would instantly turn unresponsive and not allowing any interaction (no callbacks/error messages were given out either).

**Goal:**
The goal here is to simply call `tryActivities[0]` then, await for 1 second and then return true, and prints "Fished successfully!", without any crashing.

**Suspicions:**
A suspicion I have is that the line `tryActivities.Add(new Func<bool>(() => fs(currentSlot.basicData.typeID).Result));` need some sort of await? Though I'm also unsure of how to implement that either.

Inventory inventory; (Inventory.cs)

```
    List<Func<bool>> tryActivities = new List<Func<bool>>();
    public delegate Task<bool> Fish(int ID); Fish fs;

    void Start()
    {
        fs = new Fish(activities.Fish);
        tryActivities.Add(new Func<bool>(() => fs(currentSlot.basicData.typeID).Result));//await? how?
    }

    public void Interact()//called when a button is pressed
    {
        if (TryPlaceOrUse()) print("Fished successfully!");
        else print("Fishing failed");
    }

    bool TryPlaceOrUse()
    {
        if (tryActivities[(int)currentSlot.basicData.myActivity]())//tryActivities[0] 
        return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Activities activities; (Activities.cs)

```
    public async Task<bool> Fish(int ID)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);//crashes here
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Try using a List<Func<Task<bool>>>.

Also, this question as it stands doesn't really fit the standards of https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This reduces to "How do I avoid calling `Task.Result` on a task that hasn't finished yet."

Comment: What you're trying to do here doesn't really line up with how Unity is designed to work.  I suggest looking at Coroutines: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do what you want.  This is how you'd use a list of `async` `Func`s, which is really just a list of `Func`s that return `Task`s of `bool`.

```
public class Program
{
    public delegate Task<bool> Fish(int ID);
    Fish fs;
    List<Func<Task<bool>>> tryActivities = new List<Func<Task<bool>>>();

    public async static Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        Program program = new Program();

        program.Start();

        await program.Interact();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        fs = new Fish(Activities.Fish);
        tryActivities.Add(new Func<Task<bool>>(async () => await fs(4)));//await? how? like this :)
    }

    public async Task Interact() //called when a button is pressed
    {
        if (await TryPlaceOrUse())
            Console.WriteLine("Fished successfully!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Fishing failed");
    }

    async Task<bool> TryPlaceOrUse()
    {
        if (await tryActivities[0]()) //tryActivities[0] 
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public class Activities
{
    public static async Task<bool> Fish(int ID)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);//does not crash here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! your answer turns out to be the exact thing that I've been searching for this whole time! :D